# Swift use Delegate to refresh Tableview

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have tableviewA in a viewController. I am using XIBs as cells for tableViewA. Inside those XIB, I have another tableViewB. Using delegate, I am trying to refresh tableViewB from viewController once I get data from server.

Code used are as follows. Don't know why tableViewB doesn’t get refreshed once data received from server

1.Define protocol

```
protocol tblRefresh: NSObject {
 func refreshTbl()
}
```

2.ViewController

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

weak var delegateTblRefresh : tblRefresh?

  //tableViewA defined here

   func getDataFromServer(){
     // get data from server
     self.delegateTblRefresh?.refreshTbl()
   }
}
```

3.XIB as cell of tableViewA

```
class Challengers: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, tblRefresh {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewB: UITableView!

let homeVC = HomeVC()

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    homeVC.delegateTblRefresh = self
  }

  //tableViewB defined here

  func refreshTbl() {
    tableViewB.reloadData()
  }

}
```

Comment: Where is `HomeVC` instantiated? Are you positive that it's instantiated from `HomeVC.shared` and not just `HomeVC`?

Comment: Made a correction. However it didn’t solved my problem.

Comment: So you call `let homeVC = HomeVC()` -- but where are you putting that on the screen? It seems that the `HomeVC` on the screen is probably not the same one you're referring to in `Challengers`

Answer (score 0):

1. You are creating new instance of HomeVC which is not needed.
2. You don't need to write your own delegate method to refresh you tableView cell. Just reload the table when you get data from server. For example:

   ```
   func getDataFromServer()  
   {

    // get data from server

    self.tableViewA.reloadData()

   }
   ```

Or if you want to reload only a specific cell you can do this also.

Comment: The data from server comes very frequently. Therefore, I want to refresh only the tableViewB and not refresh the whole tableViewA.

Comment: Do you want to refresh every tableViewB or a specific tableViewB?

Comment: And the way you are writing delegate is wrong.

Comment: Arnab Ahamed Siam - How is it wrong?? What is the correct way??

Comment: You can reload any cell of tableView you want from your home view Controller.